# file_get_contents on specific URL

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a specific URL which I cannot retrive the source code from using `file_get_contents`.

Can anyone help me get the source code of the URL below or does anyone have an idea why it does not work on that specific URL?

The URL is:
http://www.lectio.dk/lectio/285/SkemaNy.aspx?type=elev&elevid=1628118635

The following returns nothing.

```
$source = file_get_contents('http://www.lectio.dk/lectio/285/SkemaNy.aspx?type=elev&elevid=1628118635');
echo $source;
```

Comment: They might have some user-agent filtering. Try emulating the same user-agent in a browser and see if it ends up empty as well.

Comment: Your example returns content here.

Comment: The owners may be blocking the useragent that PHP uses for that. Consider using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) if available.

Comment: @jishi and @gms8994 I just tried using cURL and setting the user agent to Mozilla but I still don't get any output. As `file_get_contents()` is working for @fiskfisk and `stream_get_contents()` is working for @Michiel Pater it seems that the issue is at my host. I find it strange as it is all working perfectly on any other URL than the one mentioned in my original post.

Comment: They don't happen to be hosted in the same environment? Same network that is.

Comment: @jishi You are right. All the sites I can retrive the source of is on the same host. That's strange. I have been able to use `file_get_contents()` on my host.

Comment: PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE don't use `file_get_contents`. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-readfiles/

Comment: @user257493 Am I missing something? That article you linked to doesn't seem to say anything bad about `file_get_contents()`. In fact, it seems to suggest it's fine for precisely the use mentioned in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an error at my host which is now solved. I am sorry for wasting your time but I am glad that you wanted to help.

Comment: What error you had on that time to resolve the host. because I am having same issue with the specific url. Please help me in that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you share the same host as that site, and you use some sort of NAT/SAT mapping between internal and external IP.

Your server resolves www.lectio.dk into 257.34.23.1 but the actual internal IP of your server is 10.4.5.101.

Your server isn't aware of the external IP because the firewall can't connect to it's own external IP like that (it's possible to configure though).

Solution:

add www.lectio.dk into your hosts file and have it map to your internal IP.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the site generates it's contents with javascript so thats the reason you can't get the contents.

Comment: If that were the case, file_get_contents would have to return something -- at the very least, it would have to return the Javascript.